# UISearchBar in UINavigatioBar titleView with SearchDisplayController

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I'm trying to create a search bar in a navigation bar's titleview (along with some buttons on the left and right) whos function should mirror something like Facebook iOS' search bar.

The problem I'm having is that the searchResultsTableView never shows up when I click into the search bar.

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UISearchBar *searchBar;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UISearchDisplayController *searchController;
```

in my viewDidLoad I have

```
self.searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc]init];
self.searchBar.delegate=self;
self.searchController=[[UISearchDisplayController alloc] initWithSearchBar:self.searchBar
                                                        contentsController:self];
self.searchController.delegate=self;
self.searchController.searchResultsDataSource = self;
self.searchController.searchResultsDelegate =self;

self.navigationItem.titleView = self.searchBar;
```

This does not show the results table view upon clicking on it, nor does it expand the bar out.

However, if I place the searchBar in the table's headview, everything works perfectly fine:

```
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchBar;
```

I have also tried:

```
self.searchController.displaysSearchBarInNavigationBar = YES;
```

but it doesn't expand the searchbar into the entire navigationBar and fails to dim/bring up resultsTableView after the first time.

Any clarification / help would be greatly appreciated :)

Thank you,

Comment: Hi. Did you managed to resolve this? I have exactly the same issue as well.

Comment: I ended up using storyboard to add a searchDisplayController to the hierarchy and connected outlets/delegates in story board. Then, in viewDidLoad I just have: self.searchController.displaysSearchBarInNavigationBar = YES; Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks. I couldn't use IB so I ended up writing my own searchController. It wasn't that hard actually.